# Find a list of available Glyph Names to use for FontAwesomeIcons in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder

I am designing a JavaFX-Stage using SceneBuilder. I want to include icons from FontAwesome. Therefore, I downloaded the fontawesome-8-2.jar from mvnrepository: [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.jensd/fontawesomefx/8.2). I have added this jar-file to SceneBuilder using its Library Manager.
Why did I download the 8-2.jar and not 8-9.jar? Well, whenever I include the jar-file using the Library Manager of SceneBuilder, for 8-9.jar only the GlyphBrowser and Glyph-Stack are included. But I am interested in FontAwesomeIcon! This seems to be the first bug.

Anyways, after including the 8-2.jar in SceneBuilder, I can select a FontAwesomeIcon. I can change the icon by changing the Glyph Name within the properties-register. Glyph Names such as CLOSE and UMBRELLA work. The issue that I have, however, is that I just don't know the Glyph Names of all available icons. I cannot figure out which glyphs I can choose from.

I tried to figure this out by checking [this](https://fontawesome.com/start) website. When searching for an icon called "address" for example, this website displays a selection of suitable icons, one of which is called "map-marker". But this is not a valid Glyph Name. I tried it out and the default ANCHOR glyph does not change.

I am really kind of frustrated by now. Does anyone know where to find a list of available Glyph Names?

I know that many people seem to be using the FontAwesomeFX GlyphBrowser [here](https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser/blob/master/README.md) for this purpose. The problem is that my JavaFX application was built using the newest release (I think it is JavaFX 11). And the GlyphBrowser does not work with this release - I verified this statement through [this](https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser/issues/4) forum entry.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution is to use the bootstrap icon, download it from bootstrap's for each icon you need. Save to your project directory.

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

1. Chose and download icon from here:https://icons.getbootstrap.com/
2. save the icon (SVG file) you need to your project
3. open scene using shcene builder, place SVG path control where ever in your layout
   [Library search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8HeN.png)

[inpector>Properties> Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0ILP.png)

Copy paste "path" of SVG file you download before frombiitsrap.
You can get the path by doble click SVG file using your IDE.( i am using Intelijj IDE)

for example,the path like this:
M11 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7h1V2zm1 12h2V2h-2v12zm-3 0V7H7v7h2zm-5 0v-3H2v3h2z

4.paste this path to Content properties in schene builder,in the right top of schen builder.
clik your SVG Path , open properties-> content: paste the path in the content

hope you understand my explanation,
Nice coding

Answer (score -1):

1. Chose and download icon from here:https://icons.getbootstrap.com/
2. save the icon (SVG file) you need to your project
3. open scene using shcene builder, place SVG path control where ever in your layout
   [Library search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8HeN.png)

[inpector>Properties> Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0ILP.png)

Copy paste "path" of SVG file you download before from bootstrap.it is free
You can get the path by double click SVG file using your IDE.( i am using Intelijj IDE)

for example,the path like this:
M11 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7h1V2zm1 12h2V2h-2v12zm-3 0V7H7v7h2zm-5 0v-3H2v3h2z

4.paste this path to Content properties in schene builder,in the right top of schene builder.
click your SVG Path, open properties-> content: paste the path in the content

hope you understand my explanation,
Nice coding

Comment: why do you duplicate your answer? Voted to delete ..